# Recommended way to run a Docker Compose stack in production?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

I have a couple of compose files (docker-compose.yml) describing a simple Django application (five containers, three images).

I want to run this stack in production - to have the whole stack begin on boot, and for containers to restart or be recreated if they crash. There aren't any volumes I care about and the containers won't hold any important state and can be recycled at will.

I haven't found much information on using specifically docker-compose in production in such a way. [The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/) is helpful but doesn't mention anything about starting on boot, and I am using Amazon Linux so don't (currently) have access to Docker Machine. I'm used to using supervisord to babysit processes and ensure they start on boot up, but I don't think this is the way to do it with Docker containers, as they end up being ultimately supervised by the Docker daemon?

As a simple start I am thinking to just put `restart: always` on all my services and make an init script to do `docker-compose up -d` on boot. Is there a recommended way to manage a docker-compose stack in production in a robust way?

EDIT: I'm looking for a 'simple' way to run the equivalent of `docker-compose up` for my container stack in a robust way. I know upfront that all the containers declared in the stack can reside on the same machine; in this case I don't have need to orchestrate containers from the same stack across multiple instances, but that would be helpful to know as well.

Comment: So you don't necessarily want a full blown orchestrator, but rather some sort of single server thing that ensures `docker compose up` stays up? Like monit for docker compose or something?

Comment: @TimoLehto I've never encountered monit before, but from a glance I'd say 'monit for docker compose' would be fairly near what I'm looking for - get everything up and running on boot, and restart containers (within reason) if they fail

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compose is a client tool, but when you run `docker-compose up -d` all the container options are sent to the Engine and stored. If you specify `restart` as `always` (or preferably `unless-stopped` [to give you more flexibility](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/restart-policies-restart)) then you don't need run `docker-compose up` every time your host boots.

When the host starts, provided you have [configured the Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/) to start on boot, Docker will start all the containers that are flagged to be restarted. So you only need to run `docker-compose up -d` **once** and Docker takes care of the rest.

As to orchestrating containers across multiple nodes in a Swarm - the preferred approach will be to use [Distributed Application Bundles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/bundles/), but that's currently (as of Docker 1.12) experimental. You'll basically create a bundle from a local Compose file which represents your distributed system, and then deploy that remotely to a Swarm. Docker moves fast, so I would expect that functionality to be available soon.

Comment: This is the simplest solution - I didn't realise `restart: always` persisted across Docker daemon restarts as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can find in their [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/compose/production/) more information about using docker-compose in production. But, as they mention, `compose` is primarily aimed at development and testing environments.

If you want to use your containers in production, I would suggest you to use a suitable tool to orchestrate containers, as [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/).

Comment: The documentation you linked to is out of date. Kubernetes looks interesting but the learning curve looks steep and doesn't work natively with docker-compose from what little I've read.

Comment: I have updated my replied with the most recent documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can organize your Django application as a [swarmkit](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit) **[service](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/blob/35dd848e486977d24aba2c031467385ead847823/design/nomenclature.md#service)** (docker 1.11+), you can orchestrate the execution of your application with Task.

[Swarmkit has a restart policy](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit#features) (see [swarmctl flags](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/blob/master/cmd/swarmctl/service/flagparser/restart.go))

> **Restart Policies**: The orchestration layer monitors tasks and reacts to failures based on the specified policy.
>   The operator can define restart conditions, delays and limits (maximum number of attempts in a given time window). SwarmKit can decide to restart a task on a different machine. This means that faulty nodes will gradually be drained of their tasks.

Even if your "cluster" has only one node, the orchestration layer will make sure your containers are always up and running.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you use AWS so why don't you use [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ecs/)  which is built for what you ask. You create an application which is the pack of your 5 containers. You will configure which and how many instances EC2 you want in your cluster.

You just have to convert your docker-compose.yml to the specific Dockerrun.aws.json which is not hard.

AWS will start your containers when you deploy and also restart them in case of crash

Comment: ECS would be good but in this instance I'm not in control of the AWS infrastructure and have to use provided EC2 instances